# Como filtrar para mostrar só os campos necessários em uma classe utilizando Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

Estou utilizando Gson para trabalhar com json, digamos que tenha essa classe

```
class Track(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Long,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("modality") val modality: String,
    @SerializedName("paper") val paper: Int,
    @SerializedName("popper") val popper: Int,
    @SerializedName("plate") val plate: Int,
    @SerializedName("disappear") val disappear: Int,
    @SerializedName("minRound") val minRound: Int,
    @SerializedName("penalty") val penalty: Int,
    @SerializedName("maxPoint") val maxPoint: Int,
    @SerializedName("order") val order: Int)
```

e estou utilizando isso para pegar todas as Tracks

```
 val trackType = object : TypeToken<List<Track>>() {}.type
 val modalities = Gson().fromJson<List<Track>>("json", trackType)
```

mais ele me tráz todos os campos, como eu faço para tipo filtrar só tipo para pegar o id e o name?

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa se vc não quer lidar com o objeto com todos os campos, vc pode criar um hashMap e inserir os dados da lista nele, usando uma key, value e depois destruir a lista "completa"

```
    private val mPriorityCache = hashMapOf<Int, String>()
    fun setCache(list: List<PriorityEntity>) {
        for (item in list) {
            mPriorityCache.put(item.id, item.description)
        }
    }
```